# Get height of a BottomSheet so that recyclerview can always stay above it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

```
  View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);



   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20.4sp"
                    android:transitionName="profile" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/options"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"


                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="#efefef"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:reverseLayout="true"

            app:stackFromEnd="true" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"

        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/recommendation_keyboard_paginated"></include>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have the following relative layout being used as a bottomsheet. How can i get it's height during a runtime instance.
Basically, my activity consists of a list (recyclerview) and I want to keep the recyclerview above the bottomsheet whenever the sheet is displayed. RIght now, it gets hidden behind the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

change your layout to this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rootview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

                app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20.4sp"
                        android:transitionName="profile" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/options"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@null"


                        />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="#efefef"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:reverseLayout="true"

                app:stackFromEnd="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"

            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"

            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <include layout="@layout/recommendation_keyboard_paginated"></include>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I did try it, however, in that case ` app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"` don't work.
It warns me `unexpected namespace prefix app found for relativelayout`
It spoils the original hierarchy of the bottomsheet layout.
Basically, bottom sheet layout always needs to be separate from the other layout content except the root layout which is `coordinatorlayout`

Comment: try adding parent layout **RelativeLayout** then use **layout_above="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"** to your linear layout